# Concatenate multiple row and sum on a specific column

Tags: pandas

I want to concatenate multiple row into a single row. I manage to concatenate the row, however, when I try to apply sum based on a specific column, it gave me an error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`

```
Item    Sum     Brand    Type    User   ID
ABC      5       High     Zinc   John   20A
CDD      3       Low      Iron   Bail   10B
ABC     10       High     Zinc   John   20A
CDD    200       Low      Iron   Bail   10B
```

Below is my code:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','User','Type','Brand']).agg({'Item':''.join, 'Sum':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Desired Output:

```
Item   Sum    Brand    Type   User   ID
ABC    15     High    Zinc   John   20A
CDD    203    Low     Iron    Bail  10B
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Your code works for me, have you entered consistent data in the 'Sum' column?

Comment: @FrancisWebb theres some blank in Sum column which I already assign `df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)`

Comment: I imagine this is where the error lies, you could try f.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True) if replacing empty values with zero values is valid for your case

Comment: It's likely your `Item` column contains numeric type. Try convert everything to string first: `df.Item = df.Item.astype(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Brand', 'Type', 'User', 'ID'],values=['Sum'], columns=['Item'], aggfunc=sum).stack().reset_index()


            Brand   Type    User    ID  Item    Sum
    0       High    Zinc    John    20A ABC     15.0
    1       Low     Iron    Bail    10B CDD     203.0
```